# 2002 Honda CRV Sputtering engine

Tags: engine, honda, crv

The engine is sporadically sputtering when I attempt to start it. Happens intermittently; engine not always cold.   Mileage is 130k. Spark plugs, wires, or sensor?  Put in gas treatment with no noticeable change.

Comment: There are so many things that could be causing that: fuel filter, fuel pump, injectors, plugs, and many more. The best first step is to get the OBD codes read as they might tell you what the problem is. Many auto parts stores will do that for you for free.

Comment: Leaky vacuum hose?